# Install Apache Package on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-commons

I'm trying to get started with [Http Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) with Java on Eclipse, but the IDE complains that the libraries are missing.

In particular I'm trying to compile [this](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientWithResponseHandler.java) example but eclipse complain that the import declaration is pointing towards an unknow library...

Could someone point me to a tutorial on how to install the apache libraries on eclipse?

I tried to download the sources or binaries and adding them to the path with no avail... thanx :D

Comment: You don't "install" libraries in Eclipse, you add them to the build path. You need to explain better what you've tried to do.

Comment: I edited... I hope now is more clear, thanx :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They need to go in the compiletime/runtime classpath. It's called *Build Path* in an IDE like Eclipse.

Here's the easiest way:

- Drop the JARs in the project folder.
- Select the JARs, right click, choose *Build Path* and then *Add to Build Path*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- Download the HTTPClient jars and save them in the project.
- Right click the project name and navigate to `Build Path`.
- Select `Configure Build Path`
- Select the `Libraries` tab.
- Click `Add Jars...`
- Locate and select the JARs you want and click `OK`.