# Add the jar files from Apache Package on Eclipse

Tags: apache, jar

My question is the same as the ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706212/install-apache-package-on-eclipse) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826195/import-org-apache-error-http-client), and several other links.
I want to use a class which imports

```
 org.apache.commons.math3.stat.regression.SimpleRegression
```

I did the following: I downloaded both the binary and source from [here](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) HttpClient 4.2.3 (GA). In the lib directory, there were several jar files, I added them all to the project, and then followed the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706212/install-apache-package-on-eclipse).
Still, the Eclipse does not recognize the

```
org.apache.commons.math3
```

What have I done wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpClient is the wrong library. The math library you are looking for can be found here: http://commons.apache.org/math/

After downloading the math jar you should follow the steps described here: [Install Apache Package on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706212/install-apache-package-on-eclipse)